# How to get full value of number input in Firefox with zeros

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

Firefox shows just *1* when I type *1,00* in the input. All other browsers I tested are showing *1,00*. How can I read the **full** value of the input in Firefox **with** the zeros after the comma? The type of the input has to be *number* and can't be *text*.

```js
$("#input").keyup(function() {
  $("#output").text($("#input").val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="input" min="0.00" step="0.01" max="999.99">
<p id="output"></p>
```

Edit: For me it doesn't matter if decimal mark is a comma or a period.
See the [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWeUT.png) of the difference between Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: chrome doesnt even allow commas; are u sure u tested it in chrome?

Comment: If you want commas in your number it has to be a string.

Comment: @RajkumarSomasundaram This works fine in Chrome. However `1.00` also becomes `1`

Comment: Set it as text and validate the input to be \d+,\d\d[

Comment: @Juan OP is asking for comma, not dot (period).

Comment: Yes, I tested it with Chrome. Maybe you have to use a point instead of a comma. I think it depends on your location.

Comment: Location has no bearing on it. Numbers must be delimited by a period, not a comma.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Thx, I hadn't noticed that

Comment: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.8.3

Comment: @evolutionxbox You should be pointing to HTML specs.

Comment: Check [this page for the support](https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/html5-input-number-localization) . Also try adding `lang` attribute as `en-150` as shown in the linked page.

Comment: Maybe check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341325/how-to-force-to-display-a-number-with-a-comma-with-input-type-number

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's a comma or a period. The problem is that in Firefox the value is different than the input.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let output = document.getElementById('output');

document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('input', function (e) {
  output.innerText = e.currentTarget.value.replace('.', ',');
});
```

```html
<input type="number" id="input" min="0.00" step="0.01" max="999.99">
<p id="output"></p>
```

Comment: Still doesn't allow commas.

Comment: Hmm... Wait a munute

Comment: This is just the same as what OP posted but without jQuery.

Comment: Same behavior like in my snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the value to a float and use the [`toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) function to always print the number with two decimals.

```js
$("#input").keyup(function() {
  $("#output").text(
    parseFloat($("#input").val()).toFixed(2)
  );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="input" min="0.00" step="0.01" max="999.99">
<p id="output"></p>
```

Comment: This has effect on the input-text but not the value.

Comment: I thought that was the point, why else did you include the javascript?

Comment: It's just a short snippet of my project. I want to read the value from the input and work with it. But for this work it has to be _1.00_ and not _1_.