# Why the <br> element has more height than line-height

Tags: html, css

I am having a weird problem , either I don't know how `<br/>` works or I am missing something here.My paragraphs have line height of 24px. I want to have a line break (empty line) between the text but when I use `<br/>` tag it creates an empty line with too much space (36 px) according to paint.net so what I am doing wrong?

Isn't line break supposed to have same height as line-height property? If yes why isn't that working and if not then what is the solution?

```
<p>
   Greenfields Counselling and Psychotherapy is a counselling practice that lives and works out of the principles for counselling and psychotherapy as set down by Carl Rogers.
  <br/>
  <br/>
  Counselling at Greenfields is strictly confidential and we understand that this can be a difficult time for you.
</p>
```

Here is the css:

```
p {
  line-height: 24px;
}
```

Here is the demo: http://contestlancer.com/greenFields/?page_id=41
Look at the space after  the word happen.

Ahmar.

Comment: Unrelated: [Do I need a "/" at the end of an <img> or <br> tag, etc.?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15149641/do-i-need-a-at-the-end-of-an-img-or-br-tag-etc)

Comment: pleeeeeaaase, do not just link to a page to let us view the problem there, write up sample code `INTO YOUR POST`, because as soon as you have fixed this on your site (hopefully soon), this question will become useless to others.

Comment: Ok Adding code now @DrCopyPaste

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net is better

Comment: no its not, jsfiddle is a nice additive, but fiddles might get deleted or be unavailable at some time, too ;)

Comment: "According to paint.net", I strongly recommend that u start to learn proper tools. Use firebug for firefox and default web inspector for chrome. In those addons u can see elements dimensions without the need to calc them for yourself

Comment: The post is not about tools I know I shouldn't use paint dot net but still it doesn't change the fact that space is too much see for your self @DarkBee

Comment: @DrCopyPaste code added

Comment: @AhmarAli its a comment, not an answer

Comment: The code in the question does not match the code in the linked page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems perfectly fine to me... if you get rid of one of the `<br>`s I measured distance between "facilitate"'s f and "Counseling"'s C to be `13px`. If I put it back in again it is `37px`.

`37px - 13px = 24px = the line-height you set = everything is okay` ;)

(measuring done via Greenshot ;))

So if you are not satisfied with the height of your `<br>` you should add a special condition for that to your css:

```
br
{
    line-height: <desired_value>;
}
```

PS: So to clarify further, `line-height` is not the same as the space between two letters in two lines...

Answer (score 0):

You can remove that line-height spacing by this technique.

```
br{
    display: block;
    height: 0;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cWVcY/)

Answer (score 0):

The `<br />` tag is for line breaks. You can use the CSS line-height property to control distance between lines, if you want to look at it that way.

for large distances between lines, is better to use `<p>` tags for every line, in which you can control the height.

```
   jsfiddle.net/efortis/f6ju2/
```