# Opening closing tags

Tags: html

What is the difference between these two lines of code:

```
<img src="img.png" alt="" />
```

and

```
<img src="img.png" alt="">
```

I have a friend that doesn't always close her tags and I feel like that is bad practice but I don't know exactly why. I always open and close my tags but is there any effect of not properly closing them or is it just "something people do".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do I need a "/" at the end of an <img> or <br> tag, etc.?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15149641/do-i-need-a-at-the-end-of-an-img-or-br-tag-etc)

Comment: You're referring to "self closing tags". See relevant discussion here for example [Are self-closing tags valid in HTML5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558119/are-self-closing-tags-valid-in-html5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XHTML requires all tags to be closed.  That makes the file valid XML and therefore parsable by XML parsers.

HTML 4 doctypes and the new HTML5 doctype do not require this.

So it basically depends on the doctype whether you should close all tags or not.

I prefer to close all tags at all times.

Answer (score 0):

Its HTML validation. Both probably work but as HTML has progressed, what is considered valid code has changed.