# Getting W3C "document type does not allow element "LINK" here" even though links are in head?

Tags: html, validation, w3c, w3c-validation

I am running my site through the W3C validator and getting the error:

```
document type does not allow element "LINK" here"
```

for my external CSS style sheet links.

However, my links *are* within my head tags:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
 <html>

<head>

<title>Title</title>

<meta name="description" content="[[*description]]" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />

</head>
```

Would anyone know why this is occurring?

I am using the ModX Revo CMS if that matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The link isn't in the head.

You are using HTML 4 so `/` will end a tag. This means that `<meta />` is the same as `<meta>>` which is the same as `<meta>&gt;`.

You can't have character data in the `<head>` but the end tag for `<head>` and the start tag for `<body>` are optional. Therefore, `<meta />` is the same as:

```
<meta>
</head>
<body>
&gt;
```

Since the link element appears after this, it is in the body.

Get rid of the `/`. You aren't writing XHTML.

Comment: Related: [Do I need a "/" at the end of an `<img>` or `<br>` tag, etc.?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15149657)