# CSS last-child selects all?

Tags: css, sass

I've been trying to figure out why my code below doesn't work as expected.
Basically I want the ups `img` to have `width: 60px` and fedex `img` to have `width: 100px`.

My mark up is:

```
<div class="delivery-services">
    <span>Delivery Services</span>
    <br>
    <a href="#"><img src="img/fedex.png" alt="fedex" /></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="img/ups.png" alt="ups" /></a>
</div>
```

SCSS is:

```
.delivery-services {

  &:nth-child(3) img  {
    width: 100px;
  }

  &:last-child img {
    width: 60px;
  }
}
```

But it appears that both img are affected by `last-child`!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15149641/do-i-need-a-at-the-end-of-an-img-or-br-tag-etc for unrelated issue about closing `img` tag.

Comment: Thanks, this is the pen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YGNgkj

Comment: Well, `delivery-services` **is** the last child of its parent. Try adding a space after your `&`. The devtools style inspector is your friend here.

Comment: @Jim, take a look at my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39652886/2545680), I've explained what happens under the hood

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how a browser processes your selector `.delivery-services:last-child img`:

1. Find the element with the class `.delivery-services` and make sure it's the last child. It finds `<div class="delivery-services">` and it's indeed a last child. If you changed your HTML a bit like this:

   ```
   <div class="delivery-services">
       <span>Delivery Services</span>
       <br>
       <a href="#"><img src="img/fedex.png" alt="fedex" /></a>
       <a href="#"><img src="img/ups.png" alt="ups" /></a>
   </div>
   <div>I am last child now</div>`
   ```

   You would see that your selector doesn't match any `img` element.
2. Find all `img` elements inside the element found on first step

That's why the style `width: 60px;` is applied to all `img` elements.

I would also advise you to use classes on those images. `nth-child` selector is a good fit for recurring patters, like, for example, every 3rd row has to have green background.

Here is the fix to your problem if you need to use `nth-child` selector:

```
.delivery-services {

  :nth-child(3) img  {
    width: 100px;
  }

  :last-child img {
    width: 60px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Im on scss so in my file it should be `&:nth-..` (y)

Comment: @Jim, you can accept my answer if it answers your question :). If you write like this `&:nth-.`, it will be what you had in the beginning. My version should work OK.

Answer (score 1):

Right now you have .delivery-services::nth-child(3), which means it applies to the .delivery-services element that is the 3rd child of a parent.  That's not what you're looking for. You are looking for an `<a>` that is the 3rd child of .delivery-services.  So you need your CSS to be:

```
.delivery-services {

  & a:nth-child(3) img  {
    width: 100px;
  }

  & a:last-child img {
    width: 60px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please proofread your posts. You will need to escape `<a>` to make sure it doesn't get swallowed. Also, why are the ampersands required here at all? Or the `a` for that matter?

Comment: This works! :) I didn't know i was selecting the `.delivery-services`. This topic is kind of confusing to me up until now tbh. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah torazaburo is correct, my css works without extra `&`

Answer (score 1):

When working with CSS, you have to consider the order of operations. In the example you provided, think about the hierarchy that. When applying the style it is setting it to the top and working down. For instance, delivery-services -> a -> img. To apply this to the sub classes, understand you are looking for the image inside the first a. Therefore, I'd set it up similar to:

```
.delivery-services a:nth-child(4) img{
    width: 100px;
  }
.delivery-services a:nth-child(3) img{
  width: 60px;
}
```

However, for specific instances such as this, I'd assign a different class to each instance or inline styling. nth-child is ideal for loops and iterations.