# Bootstrap grid 3 column layout doesn't work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, footer

I think I looked everywhere and tried everything. 
I want to make a footer for a website with 3 columns - in each one there's h4 header and image (png icon). Instead of getting 3 columns I got 1 column with everything stacked under each other.
HTML code:

```html
<div class="footer">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <h4>Instagram</h4>
            <a href="#" target="_blank"/><img src="img/instagram.png"/></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <h4>Facebook</h4>
            <a href="#" target="_blank"/><img src="img/facebook.png"/></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <h4>LinkedIn</h4>
            <a href="#" target="_blank"/><img src="img/linkedin.png"/></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Any reason why? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. Did you check that everything (css & js) is loading without errors?

Comment: Does it work using col-md-4?

Comment: try col-md or col-lg

Comment: This is a guess, but it might have something to do with your anchor tags. You are self-closing them all, so the </a> closes might be confusing it. Remove the forward slashes from the ends of all your opening <a> tags.

Comment: I tried to do that - nothing changed. Also I tried all combinations of col-md-4, col-lg-3 etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you are not getting the results you expect from bootstrap is likely due to you missing a resource.

Please make sure that you have the following included in the  section of your document.

```
    <head> 
       <meta charset="utf-8">
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
```

CodePen example: https://codepen.io/CapySloth/pen/gRGNxa

Answer (score 0):

Replace all entities of `<a href="#" target="_blank"/>` with `<a href="#" target="_blank">` and will be happy!

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <h4>Instagram</h4>
        <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="img/instagram.png"/></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <h4>Facebook</h4>
        <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="img/facebook.png"/></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <h4>LinkedIn</h4>
        <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="img/linkedin.png"/></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just to contribute with discussion, in my case I haven't any error on tags, but I had to change the col-*-4 to 32% in css , and everything works fine

Answer (score 0):

**1st**:

```
<a href="#" target="_blank"/><img src="img/instagram.png"/></a>
```

Should be

```
<a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="img/instagram.png"></a>
```

For img there is not need to close it with `/` REF: [Do I need a "/" at the end of an <img> or <br> tag, etc.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15149641/do-i-need-a-at-the-end-of-an-img-or-br-tag-etc)

**2nd**: use `col-xs-4` if you want them to always be 3 item in one row. (all screen size will fall into the xs if nothing else is defined (lg/md/sm etc))

**3rd**: could be your reference not setup properly. try those:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <h4>Instagram</h4>
        <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="img/instagram.png"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <h4>Facebook</h4>
        <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="img/facebook.png"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <h4>LinkedIn</h4>
        <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="img/linkedin.png"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I didn;t setup the reference before - all sorted now, thanks a lot!

Comment: @MariuszS. ok Cool =D